# Html displayed as text after upgrading rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After the security issues found in rails lately i upgraded my app to the 3.0.19 version. After upgrading i started to see this on the views

< div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline" > < input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="NUvSsQPtm09ho5A5qlfuXTQ6ipgmbA80jALLRGG5CdY=" / > < /div >

displayed like text.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

```
"<div>...</div>".html_safe
```

Rails 3 changed the way html strings are treated. Check out [this article](http://origami.co.uk/blog/2010/02/rails-3-html-escaping) to learn more.

Comment: This part of code is auto generated by rails on the forms. I dont see it in the template so i dont know where to add the html_safe part if the content does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is because with rails > 3 html safe comes by default, to avoid this use `raw`

```
Ex: raw ("<h1>Header</h1>") => will print html h1 tag
```

HTH